# Account unavailable when non-www

Tags: web, virtualhost

I have my hosting account "mydomain.com" with ServersFree.com. When I try to access from http://mydomain.com, it says "Account unavailable: Maybe account have been moved, deleted, suspended or not activated yet. The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future.", but if I enter from http://www.mydomain.com, it loads perfectly.

FTP is working correctly.

I thought that it was a problem with DNS, and I tried to fix it, but nothing occured. Here they are:

```
 @ | 86400 | NS |     ns1.serversfree.com
 @ | 86400 | NS |     ns2.serversfree.com
 @ | 86400 | NS |     ns3.serversfree.com
 @ | 86400 | NS |     ns4.serversfree.com
 @ | 14400 |  A |     31.170.166.124
ftp| 14400 |  A |     31.170.166.124
www| 14400 |  A |     31.170.166.124
 @ | 14400 | MX | 0 | mx1.serversfree.com
```

I've tried to contact theme and search the internet, but nobody answers and I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the server administrator using ServersFree.com's helpdesk: [cpanel.serversfree.com/helpdesk](http://cpanel.serversfree.com/helpdesk) or send them an email [here](http://www.serversfree.com/server-support/) or support@serversfree.com.